# Force to Open HTML in IE8 instead of any other versions of IE?

Tags: javascript, html

I have designed a HTML Page and I want that whenever user opens in IE, than by default it should open in IE8 Standards version of IE.
Instead if there is IE9 or IE10 it should take IE8 as default.

Comment: On my PC there is no other IE than IE11, so how should it be opened there?

Comment: Why? IE8 mode is slow, buggy and you won't get it for non-IE browsers. You should almost certainly be fixing in the page instead of asking modern browsers to be buggy.

Comment: You could do this for testing the page,  but in that case you should use the developers tools. Make your code cross browser instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can instruct Internet Explorer 9 and newer to render in IE 8 mode with:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

This is [documented on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff966528%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

See the comments on the question for why you should not do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this for testing purposes:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

This forces IE 8 to display the page in Internet Explorer Standards mode.

Or

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

This forces IE 8 to use the !DOCTYPE declaration in the page to determine the rendering mode.

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/dd835379.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here are both the HTTP and the  tag ways of setting X-UA-Compatible:

HTTP:

```
Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=8"
```

Meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

http://farukat.es/journal/2009/05/245-ie8-and-the-x-ua-compatible-situation